# How to correctly use setInterval with forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I recently found node's `forever` package and have been trying to understand how it works. I tried searching but that didn't help much.

1. Is there any option in `forever` to run scripts periodically? For e.g. if I want it to do something every 5 minutes, is there any option for that? or I will have to use `setInterval` for that?

Eg :

```
var minutes = 5, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000;
var open = require('open'); 

setInterval(function() {
  open('https://stackoverflow.com');  //Open every 5 minutes
}, the_interval);
```

2. If `forever` doesn't have any such option, then in above case, how frequently is `forever` trying to run the script? I am asking this because I checked without `setInterval` and it was running once every second. So, how does it handle `setInterval`?

Comment: It sounds like cron would be a much more suitable tool for what you're trying to do.

Comment: What's the purpose of this logic? What's wrong with `setInterval`?

Comment: setInterval has nothing to do with this. forever registers that the script stopped and tries to restart it. that's all. if you have the set interval in your script then your script is running and forever is happy.

Comment: ... and what is wrong running the desired part of your script from setInterval loop? forever will just keep an eye on it that it is sound and running.

Comment: @webduvet Alright now I get it. `forever` only checks if the script is running. And if it's not, it tries to restart it, right?